# Parallax.js não funciona no Chrome para Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, parallax

O efeito parallax.js (http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/) só funciona para navegadores desktop.

Algo pode ser feito para que o efeito seja visível em dispositivos móveis?

Estou usando as classes e os atributos padrões:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/parallax.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <section id="home" class="parallax-window"  data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="img/bg/home-1280.jpg">  
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `background-attachment: fixed;` é o meu parallaxe favorito e funciona em todos os dispositivos.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que possa estar relacionado com a option "androidFix", que por default vem como true e deixa a imagem estática em mobile.

da uma olhada na última option http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/

Alterando, ficaria ficaria algo assim:

```
<section id="home" class="parallax-window"  data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="img/bg/home-1280.jpg" data-android-fix="false">  
  </section>
```

Comment: Olá, Thiago! Obrigado pela sua contribuição.

Acrescentei data-android-fix="false" na linha e a imagem parou de ser exibida no android. Estranho né?